# SQL Server Denormalize Parent Child into Single Column?

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, partitioning

I am working with MSSQL 2012 and am trying to figure out how to take a set with parent values in one column and child values in another column, and combine that into one column with the parent only shown in a single row and each respective child shown beneath it. Exercises with row_number()/partition have not been fruitful.

How can I make this happen?

Thanks.

```
set nocount on
declare @parchi table ( parenttext varchar(20) , childtext varchar(20) )
insert into @parchi values ( 'parenta' , 'childa' )
insert into @parchi values ( 'parenta' , 'childc' )
insert into @parchi values ( 'parenta' , 'childb' )
insert into @parchi values ( 'parentb' , 'child1' )
insert into @parchi values ( 'parentb' , 'child3' )
insert into @parchi values ( 'parentb' , 'child2' )


select childtext,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by parenttext order by parenttext,childtext) as tempordnum from @parchi 


-- below is shape of the result set. what i came up with does not include the parent at the top of each grouping set (pun intentional(.
parenta
childa
childb
childc
parentb
child1
child2
child3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. It first gets parents and assigns a rank to each one of them. Then it gets children and assigns parent rank again plus a child rank. At the end it gets the result from the union sorted by parent order and then child order.

You can add additional columns in `ORDER BY` part of `DENSE_RANK()` to further sort children.

```
;with cte as
(
    select distinct parenttext, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY parenttext) parentorder, 0 childorder 
    from @parchi

    union all

    select childtext, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY parenttext), DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY childtext)
    from @parchi
)

select parenttext from cte
order by parentorder, childorder
```

Answer (score 1):

try this suggestion:

you will need to select the parent, and the child separately and then u will UNION the both select.

1. select the parent, and use row_number to create the parent id (parenta id = 1, parent b id = 2)
2. select the child, and use dense_rank based on the parenttext field. this will give the child an id (childa - childc will have id = 1, child1-3 will have id = 2)
3. union the result and you will get what u want